# Bring ArcGIS Online feature service layer into MapBox

Tags: mapbox, arcgis-online

I am trying to do the following in MapBox Studio:

- Bring an existing feature service layer(s) into the MapBox style, so when updated in AGO it will automatically update in MapBox
- Obtain a mapbox style url as a result
  Is this possible? I am not sure where to begin (my coding ability is fairly limited).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not too large, you can get geoJSON from the FeatureService and then add it to your mapbox map as a geojson source.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/

Comment: Hello, thanks, I am just not sure how to add the code in. Is it possible to add the code in map box studio? The end result I am looking for is a style url.

Comment: It's not possible to add a third-party geojson source to your style in mapbox studio.  The only way to do what you're asking is to add a geojson source and layer(s) to your map after the main style is done loading.  

Here's a github thread on this issue.  There was some interest but it was not implemented: https://github.com/mapbox/studio/issues/7539